# Что выводится в консоли?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет.

1. Не понимаю, почему это в консоли выводится по-разному при различных вариантах записи:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Вот второй пример:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему, если "что-то" записать просто само по себе в консоли, то выводится В ОДНОМ ВИДЕ, а если это "что-то" запихнуть в функцию консоллог, то выведется В ДРУГОМ ВИДЕ?

Comment: потому что так работает консоль.

Comment: как это "так работает консоль"? какая разница между двумя этими записями? я спросил "почему", а ответили "потому, что так работает")

Comment: В первой выводится значение выражения. во второй - вывод регулируется функцией `log`. Вообще, что и как должна выводить консоль, нигде не специфицировано, поэтому в разных браузерах результаты могут сильно отличаться. Если интересна конкретно консоль хрома - стоит пойти в исходники и посмотреть что происходит в том или ином случае.

Answer (score 3):

Присвоив переменной значение или выражение которое его возвращает, а затем вернув его по имени переменной мы получаем значение переменной или выражение которое после вызова должно возврашать это значение. При попытке прочитать значение с помощью команды `console.log()` мы получим

> HTML-like tree

так это называется на сайте MDN, там же пишут, что `console.dir()` возвращает

> JSON-like tree

Может на вопрос я и не ответил, да и впринципе такое лучше спросить на форумах разработчиков каждого браузера индивидуально, но теперь надеюсь что-то прояснилось, ну хотя-бы где копать дальше).

Answer (score 2):

Консоль выводит результат последнего вычисления. [Функция console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log) является не стандартизированной, но на данный момент по описанию на MDN она выводит для переданного DOM-элемента его представление HTML и для переданного объекта его JSON представление.